# How to use registerContextMenu for a recyclerview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

I try to make a small file manager, I want that when holding a file or folder I get a contextual menu, and I tried to use registerForContextMenu(newRecyclerView) but it does not work for me, nothing happens at all, instead if I do it with another element like a button or an ImageView, the menu comes out perfect, and I've been googling for hours, but most of the solutions I've found are in java, and I don't know how to implement them in kotlin, one thing to keep in mind is that when handling files , the recylerview is going to be constantly changing as we navigate through the directories, what I want is a menu where I can copy, cut the file and stuff, I know there are other solutions for this, but I want to implement them with a context menu , here is MyAdapter, I don't put the Main Activity,because it's a riot

```
import...
class MyAdapter(private val newsList: 
ArrayList<News>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() 
{

private lateinit var mListener:OnItemClickListener
interface OnItemClickListener{
fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}
fun  setOnItemClicKListener(listener:OnItemClickListener){
mListener = listener

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: 
Int): MyViewHolder {
val itemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_items,
parent, false)


return MyViewHolder(itemView, mListener)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: 
Int) {

val currentItem = newsList[position]
holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
holder.tvHeading.text = currentItem.heading

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
return newsList.size
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: 
OnItemClickListener):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

val titleImage: ShapeableImageView = 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
val tvHeading:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

init{

    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: Please try to improve your code formatting. As is, it is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering the entire RecyclerView with a context menu, you should register each child view. This is because you are holding the child view, not the RecyclerView itself.

Comment: Thanks Code-Apprentice, do you know where I can access the children's view?

Comment: @Hallen By "children views", I mean the ones created by your RecylerView.Adapter subclass.